# Не отправляется письмо на почту через mail() php

Tags: php, ajax

У меня на сайте есть форма обратной связи и форма покупки товара. Форма обратной связи работает отлично и все письма приходят мгновенно и правильно, но форма покупки нет. Код там прям такой же, просто добавлены новые переменные. через $_SESSION я получаю значения товаров. Я уже и так, и так пытался, всё равно письма не приходят. Но по сути запрос работает, при нажатии на кнопку меня перебрасывает на buy.php и там условие if отрабатывает, и высвечивается alert, но письмо почему-то не уходит. В чём проблема?
вот код кнопки:

```
<form action="constructor/buy.php" method="post">
            <input type="submit" onclick="quickorder_confirm();" class="btn btn-quickorder-one" value="Оформить Заказ" style="display: block;"><i class=" fa-fw"></i></input>
        </form>
```

код buy.php

```
<?php
session_start();
    $namer = $_SESSION['n_t'];
    $counter = $_SESSION['count_t'];
    $pricer = $_SESSION['price_t'];

    $email = "secret@mail.ru";

    $tema_email = "Купить товар"; // tema 
    $text = $_POST['text_polz']; // text polz
    $num_email = $_POST['phone_polz']; // nomer telephone
    $user_email = $_POST['email_buyer']; // pochta usera
    $description_email = $_POST['comment_buyer']; // opisaniye

    if(mail($email, $tema_email, "Купить товар: ".$namer."\r\nВ количестве: x".$counter."штук > "
    ."На сумму: ".$pricer."руб".
    "Текст: ".$text."\n\rНомер телефона: ".$num_email."\n\r".
    "Почта покупателя: ".$user_email."\n\r"."Комментарий к форме: ".".
    $description_email.\n\r")){
        echo "<script>";
        echo "alert('Звонок запрошен. С вами свяжутся в ближайшее время!');";
        echo "window.location.href = '../index.php'";
        echo "</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>";
        echo "alert('Упс! Что-то пошло не так :/ ');";
        echo "window.location.href = '404.php'";
        echo "</script>";
    }
```

Comment: Вполне возможно, что попадает в спам. Попробуйте сменить тему письма

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил. Оказывается нужно было пользоваться почтой своего домена, а не мною созданного))